# How to delete files and folders but keep directory structure and leave behind a empty file instead of file itself?

Tags: python, linux, windows, bash, cmd

I want to delete files and folders but leave directory structure intact.

But also I need to keep name of files in their current path. Something like, leaving behind a empty text with same name of file instead of that file itself.

My drive format is NTFS.

Comment: If you delete folders, the directory structure won't be intact. Or did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.walk` to browse your directory structure and remplace each file with an empty one (overwrite the file:

```
import io
import os

work_dir = '.'
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(work_dir):
    for filename in filenames:
        path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        io.open(path, mode='w').close()
```

See the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Comment: You may not have access to all files, so the script should handle an `IOError` exception (Python 3 `OSError`, but `IOError` is aliased) by logging the files that it fails to overwrite. For example,  it could fail with access denied if the file permissions don't grant write access. On Windows, it could fail with a sharing violation (winerror 32) if the file is already open without write sharing, or it could fail with access denied (winerror 5) if the file is flagged to be unlinked (deleted) from the directory.

Comment: @eryksun yes, the OP should be aware of that. He can add an exception manager. Thank for your advice. He can also add a backup feature like the recycle bin.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash 4+ you can do the following to zero out all the files under a certain path:

```bash
shopt -s globstar
for file in /mnt/c/path/to/clean/**; do
    [[ -f $file ]] && : > "$file"
done
```

Comment: and If you don't have bash 4 installed:

    find /mnt/c/path/to/clean/ -type f | xargs -n 1 -P 100 -I {} "bash -c ': > {}'"

Comment: @MosheZada: please explain to me why xargs is better than `-exec cp /dev/null {} \;`.

Comment: Note that the `:` should be removed when you are really sure you want to perform the action.

Comment: @WalterA  If you are refering to the `:` before the  `> "$file"` redirection in the proposed answer, it is a noop and, while not required, it does not prevent overwriting the file to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

For a windows `cmd` solution

```dos
for /r "x:\path\to\clean" %a in (*) do ">%a" type nul
```

To run it from a batch file, percent signs need to be escaped (doubling them)

```
for /r "x:\path\to\clean" %%a in (*) do ">%%a" type nul
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd), you might want to use the [`robocopy` command](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html):

```cmd
rem // Create copy with zero-length files at temporary location:
robocopy "\path\to\your\dir" "\path\to\temp\dir" *.* /E /CREATE
rem // Move tree at temporary location onto original location:
robocopy "\path\to\temp\dir" "\path\to\your\dir" *.* /E /MOVE /IS
```